# Android: Button enabled property is not working

Tags: android

i have the String in Edit Text, i want to change change the button state through the string. Please help me out of this problem i am beginner in android. 
Here is the code.

```
String Result = jsonResult.toString();

JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Result);
int successValue = jsonResponse.getInt("success");
String messageValue= jsonResponse.getString("message");

String successStringValue = String.valueOf(successValue);
String messageStringValue = String.valueOf(messageValue);

t1.setText(messageStringValue);
String tt1=t1.getText().toString();
if (tt1 !=  "Appointment is ready."){
      b1.setEnabled(true);}
else{
      b1.setEnabled(false);}
```

Comment: it will work  your condition is wrong

Comment: If you want to compare strings you have to use `equals()` that compares values and not references. Your problem is that `==` compares references and this won't work. You need to compare values so for this reason you have to use `equals()` method.

Comment: use tt1.equalsIgnoreCase("Appointment is ready") in if()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your condition to

```
if (tt1.equalsIgnoreCase("Appointment is ready.")){
  b1.setEnabled(true);
  }
  else
   {
  b1.setEnabled(false);
   }
```

use this code for making edittext not editable

```
<EditText ...
    android:clickable="false" 
    android:cursorVisible="false" 
    android:focusable="false" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
 </EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!(tt1.equals("Some String")))
{
//enable button
}
else
{
//disable it
}
```

Stings are compared by doing ".equals()"